# How to get each char* from a long void*

Tags: c++

I have a `void *` in c++, it contains many logs, but we do not know the length of each log. how can I split it to `char*`, using regular expression or some other methods.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    void *logs = malloc(1024);
    char eachLog[100][100];
    if (logs == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    memcpy(logs, "2023/05/29 10:12:16 638377 [ debug] this is\n 1st log\n", 53);
    memcpy((char*)logs + 53, "2023/05/29 10:12:16 638378 [   err] this is 2st log\n", 52);
    memcpy((char*)logs + 105, "2023/05/29 10:12:16 638379 [  info] this is 3th log\n", 52);

    /* the logs may be like this:
    2023/05/29 10:12:16 638377 [ debug] this is\n 1st log\n2023/05/29 10:12:16 638378 [   err] this is 2st log\n2023/05/29 10:12:16 638379 [  info] this is 3th log\n
    
    What I want is:
    put the 1st log to eachLog[0];
    put the 2st log to eachLog[1];
    put the 3st log to eachLog[2];
    */

    free(logs);
    logs = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The same way you put it together - use the hardcoded values. That is the only  way unless you store some extra information in the array itself - extra `\0`, newlines, prepended lengths... Just use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @Quimby  Each log begin with the datetime, is there a way to use regular expression, such as find the first string starting with the date and extract it, then second ... I do not know if  it is feasible

Comment: Each log line ends with a newline the way you created it.  If the log lines all have only one newline and it is always at the end then you can split it on a newline.

Comment: If the log lines can have multiple newlines then matching a line starting with a date might work as long as the embedded newlines can't be followed by dates.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "C++" I only see "C" code. `void*` should not be used in C++ (except in some rare type erasure scenarios). The same is true for `malloc`/`free` (even `new`/`delete` are not recommended). And instead of `memcpy` there is `std::copy`. And lastly `eachLog` should be a `std::vector<std::string>`. Just to show you "C++" is not like "C"

Comment: @YongqiZ But how will you even know how long the array is or if it is even an array? `void*` can be anything. You are not using null-terminators at all now for the strings. Even if you have a regular expression, you will inevitably start overflow the buffer which is undefined behaviour. With using this `void*` approach you are just creating unnecessary problems for yourself for no good reason as far as I can see.

Comment: If you did want to use a regex I like this: `\d{4}/(?|0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (?|[01][0-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9](?:(?!\d{4}/(?|0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (?|[01][0-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]).)*`  with the `s` flag.  Here is an example https://regex101.com/r/K7ryIn/1

Comment: *"it [a `void *`] contains many logs"* -- a pointer contains an address, not logs. You probably mean that the pointer *points to* a sequence of characters that contains many logs. That still leaves the question of why a pointer-to-void? For the purpose of this question, why don't you start with a pointer-to-char? As in: *"I have an array of characters that contains many logs,"* Then you could ask how could the individual log entries be recovered, which would be clearer than *"split it to `char*`"*.

Comment: Before telling the computer how to do something, you should know how to do it yourself. If you were given a sequence of characters to split into log entries, how would you know where each entry began (or ended)? Define the problem in words before trying to solve it in code.

Comment: What about `std::regex` and searching for `"\\d\\d\\d\\d\\/\\d\\d\\/\\d\\d\\s*\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\s*\\d*"` as a reasonable indicator of "beginning of log line" ?

Comment: It's better to design a simpler way to split the logs. Eg: do not allow stray `\n` in logs or use `\r\n` or `\0` as fixed new log line symbol. Then it saves you from the regex works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ code to read a log file like yours (with stray newlines) would look something like this (no void*, no explicit manual memory managment, that is all done by std::string & std::vector)

Online demo : https://onlinegdb.com/peAvoAb0k

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std::string_literals;

// allow for extra newlines in log lines
std::istringstream log_file
{
    "2023/05/29 10:12:16 638377 [ debug] this is\n 1st log\n"
    "2023/05/29 10:12:16 638378 [   err] this is 2st log\n"
    "2023/05/29 10:12:16 638379 [  info] this is 3th log\n"
};

std::vector<std::string> load(std::istream& file)
{
    // debug regexes here : https://regex101.com/r/nt4FUG/1
    // make a regex that recognizes the "header" of a line
    // I left the groups () in for readability for now (they are not necessary) 
    static std::regex rx{"^(\\d{4})\\/(\\d{2})\\/(\\d{2})\\s+(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})\\s+(\\d+)\\s+\\[\\s+\\w+\\]\\s+"};
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    while (std::getline(file,line))
    {
        // if there is a header then a new log entry is found
        if (std::regex_search(line, rx))
        {
            lines.push_back(line);
        }
        else
        {
            // no header found, add the read line to the last log line read
            //lines.back() += ("\n"s + line); if you want to retain newlines
            lines.back() += line;
        }
    }

    return lines;
}

int main()
{
    auto log = load(log_file);

    for (const auto& line : log)
    {
        std::cout << line << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could  you write a rule in c please? I use c like this `reti = regcomp(&regex, "^(\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}) (\\d+) \\[\\s+\\w+\\] (.*)", 0);
// or "^(\\d{4})\\/(\\d{2})\\/(\\d{2})\\s+(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})\\s+(\\d+)\\s+\\[\\s+\\w+\\]\\s+"
reti = regexec(&regex, "2023/05/29 10:12:16 638377 [   bug] this is 1st log", 0, NULL, 0);`  all of this could not match

Comment: You do know "C++" is a different language from "C" don't you?
If you wanted a "C" answer you should have tagged your question with "C" not "C++". I cannot help you with "C" I havent used that since 1995 when I moved to "C++"

Comment: To be fair, @YongqiZ did originally tag the question with "C" (in addition to the C++ tag). Still, I agree that the question asks for a C++ answer instead of C. The most obvious is that the question states "in c++". Less obvious is the use of two non-C headers in the sample code. These would be more important than the tags for the OP to get right in the next question.